# Django class based views: Posting form data returns 302 Found status code

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm using django's generic class based view `CreateView` to upload images to a book. Here's the code:

```
# models.py
class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, help_text='Image to process')
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE, related_name='uploader')
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(os.path.split(self.image.name)[-1].split('_', 1)[-1])

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('book:upload_new', (self.book.id,))     # upload_new is linked to the view below

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Upload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image.delete(False)
        super(Upload, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)


# views.py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Upload
    fields = ("image",)
    book_id = None

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # book_id is passed as a URL parameter
        self.book_id = self.kwargs['book_id']
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_id'] = self.book_id
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        book = Book.objects.get(id=self.book_id)
        form.instance.book = book
        form.instance.language = book.language
        form.instance.uploader = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()

        # Running the command below prints
        # <TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
        # implying the upload was successful
        #
        # print(self.render_to_response(context=self.get_context_data()))

        return super(PictureCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors)
        data = json.dumps(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(content=data, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

When I'm trying to upload an image, I get a `302 Found` error for this request (as seen in the my browser's dev tools) implying the page has moved temporarily. Apart from the headers, I'm unable to see a preview or response for this request. The upload was successful though (I checked in the admin page).

Someone had [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18264715/3187043) before and the answer pointed out an error in the URL conf. However, the issue wasn't fully resolved and the OP still got a 302 status code.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: 302 Found is not an error. It is standard practice to return a 302 redirect after a successful POST request.

Comment: Your print statement in form_valid is irrelevant. The default action of the superclass method is to return a redirect; self.render_to_response will not be called at all.

Comment: All the POST requests I've seen till now returned a 200 status code.. I'm keen on knowing this because of [another issue](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/issues/72), and I thought understanding why I got a 302 might help me fix that issue.

Comment: Nope. The POST should not return 200. But the next url you get redirected to should typically return 200.

Comment: All generic form views in django inherit from `FormMixin` which returns a redirect from the `form_valid` method.
http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid

Comment: Are you returning the url for the CreateView in the model's `get_absolute_url`? Why? You should use DetailView to view specific instances.

Comment: Was using that to view instances.. will try changing that it.

Answer (score 6):

By default `form_valid` method redirects with 302 code to the `success_url` (which can be generated dynamically by overriding `get_success_url`) . So this is the normal behavior and I think a good practice. So I would not change it.

But if you really want to, you can return any other response code, for example : a 200 code with similar content than the get

```
# views.py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        book = Book.objects.get(id=self.book_id)
        form.instance.book = book
        form.instance.language = book.language
        form.instance.uploader = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()

        context = self.get_context_data()
        # You may have check and modify your context for a correct page
        # May be: add new things
        context["success"] = True

        return self.render_to_response(context))
```